# asp.net listview control - using dynamic columns on itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

Greetings smart people of stackoverflow! I have this ListView with the following itemtemplate

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
 <td><%#Eval("abc_availablearea").ToString()%>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><%#Eval("abc_classname").ToString() %>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><%#Eval("abc_division").ToString() %>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><%#Eval("abc_managername").ToString() %>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now I am trying to use dynamic field names...so something like

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
 <td><%#Eval(fieldOne).ToString()%>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><%#Eval(fieldTwo).ToString() %>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><%#Eval(fieldThree).ToString() %>&nbsp;</td>
 <td><%#Eval(fieldFour).ToString() %>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

But it's not working for me. Anyone have an idea on how to do this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could try to add the dynamic fields from the code behind in the ItemDataBound event, it would be more cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: when you say "not working"...are you getting an error message?

Comment: Al...basically the error is that it doesn't know what fieldOne, etc is

Comment: Lucian - so what you are saying add a literal on the itemTemplate, then on the ItemDataBaound event construct the row? I think that will work! Thank you...I will try tomorrow or tonight...it's 5, time to go home lol! Thanks all for your help folks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the ItemTemplate dynamically.  [Creating Web Server Control Templates Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289501%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Alison, that link is for a DataGrid control - but I dunno t might work on a Listview - will take a look - thank you.

Comment: @DevilCode: Correct.  It's the same idea.  You'll need to bind the fields programmatically in a similar fashion.  You should be able to find some sample code online after a bit of searching.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a post on it: http://start-coding.blogspot.com/2013/06/dynamic-columns-in-listview.html.

On ItemDataBound event, do something like this:

```
private void dynamicPopulateRow(HtmlTableRow row, System.Data.DataRowView drv, int iGeneration)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            // http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-enumerate-all-columns-dataviewrow-t1244448.html
            foreach (DataColumn dc in drv.Row.Table.Columns)
            {
                string sEmployeeID = drv["LoginID"].ToString();

                if (dc.ColumnName.Equals("LoginID"))
                {
                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5daxzcy(v=vs.80).aspx
                    // Define a new HtmlTableCell control.
                    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell("td");

                    // Create the text for the cell.
                    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Convert.ToString(drv[dc.ColumnName])));
                    cell.ColSpan = dc.ColumnName.Equals("LoginID") ? I_COLSPAN - iGeneration : 1;

                    // Add the cell to the HtmlTableRow Cells collection. 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else if (!(dc.ColumnName.Equals("GENERATION") ||
                            dc.ColumnName.Equals("hierarchy") ||
                            dc.ColumnName.Equals("rowNo") ||
                            dc.ColumnName.Equals("EmployeeID")))
                {
                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5daxzcy(v=vs.80).aspx
                    // Define a new HtmlTableCell control.
                    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell("td");

                    bool bIsNull = drv[dc.ColumnName] is System.DBNull;

                    Literal ltrl = new Literal();
                    ltrl.Text += "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"" + dc.ColumnName + "\"" +
                                    (bIsNull ? "" : " value=" + drv[dc.ColumnName].ToString()) +
                                    " id=\"" + sEmployeeID + "~" + dc.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_") + "\"" +//will be retrieved later
                                    " onclick=\"didModify(this)\" " +
                                    (bIsNull ? " disabled" : "") +
                                    (!bIsNull && ((int)drv[dc.ColumnName]) > 0 ? " checked>" : ">");

                    cell.Controls.Add(ltrl);
                    // Add the cell to the HtmlTableRow Cells collection. 
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                else
                {
                    //other rows
                }
            }
        }
    }
```